# Using multiple main files in VS2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I've downloaded VS2017 Community Edition and I'm working through "Programming in C" by Stephen G. Kochan.

I'd like to store all the examples in one project (possibly 1 project per chapter), however I've come across the error about multiple "main" files in one project. Before telling me I can't have multiple main's in a project, could you suggest the best way to organise these small C programs in VS2017.

I love the fact that I don't have to use a terminal compiler and would like to use VS2017 to work my way through the book.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Simply use a compiler which allows you to compile a single file without creating a project. Not sure if VS has this, but Codeblocks IDE definitely supports it. You don't want to use VS while learning C anyhow, because it is a C++ compiler with poor support for standard C.

Comment: Here's an example you can try on any free C compiler you download: `int main(void) { _Static_assert(__STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L, "If you get an error on this line, your compiler likes to lick on windows."); }`. If you get an error while compiling, it means that the compiler is completely outdated. Then you either need to get a better compiler or you need to configure the one you are using correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really want them all in one *project*.  I think you want them all in one *Solution*, with each example in its own *Project*.  That way you can switch between projects in the IDE and build/run/debug whichever one you are working on at the time.

Add a new project to your solution by right-clicking the solution in Solution Explorer and selecting Add->New Project from the menu.

Set the active project by right-clicking the project in Solution Explorer and choose "Set as startup project" from the menu.

This allows you to build each example on its own, or build all of them at once.  Each project is self-contained and generates its own executable, and you can navigate around from one project to another inside the IDE.

Comment: thanks I, started down this path, but missed the 'Set active project'. I'll try it tonight. Note: When I'm doing the assignment I add a Source file to the project and that would be the 'main'. That source file will be the only one in the project. Seems like a lot of overhead, however I think this is the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

A typical case of "assignments" in a course. In that case you can create one module (c file) for each assignment and call the current assignment from your main. Now you have all assignments in a single project, so you can easily look them up. Assignments completed you can comment-out.

Comment: But there may be issues with global variables having the same in 2 or more different assignments

Comment: @Michael Walz, then you make these `static` in each module, or you choose different names.

Comment: Sure, but the average beginner wouldn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile and run your `C` files individually from command line.

This is not ideal when using an `IDE`.

Your other option is to use [add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_executable.html?highlight=add_executable) command in `cmake`

> Adds an executable target called  to be built from the source
>   files listed in the command invocation. The  corresponds to the
>   logical target name and must be globally unique within a project. The
>   actual file name of the executable built is constructed based on
>   conventions of the native platform (such as .exe or just
>   ).